# Bazaar - is it possible to update multiple projects/branches with single commit?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

I have situation like this:
One project composed of its own files and using two independent libraries.
Three independent branches in three separate subdirectories, lets say: prj,lib1,lib2
lib1 and lib2 is actively developed with project.
Currently I perform all repo operations independently on each directory.
Is it possible to handle them all together - one status/commit/add operation on all
branches involved in project?